# Symfony 2 phpbb integration

Tags: symfony, phpbb3

I'm trying to integrate phpbb with symfony2 app.I just want to use user details from phpbb and in symfony2 app i even dont have user model/entity.
I want if user is logged in phpbb forum and access symfony2 app to get some data from phpbb session and display it.
in `app.php` i tried:

```
define('IN_PHPBB', true);
$phpbb_root_path = (defined('PHPBB_ROOT_PATH')) ? PHPBB_ROOT_PATH : __DIR__.'/forum/';
$phpEx = substr(strrchr(__FILE__, '.'), 1);
include($phpbb_root_path . 'common.' . $phpEx);
//Start session management
$user->session_begin();
$auth->acl($user->data);
```

in $user->data there is needed information, but when app tries to create request

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
```

i get an error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::createRequestFromFactory() must be of the type array, object given, called in /home/g/projects/danger-cs/cs/app/bootstrap.php.cache on line 482 and defined in /home/g/projects/danger-cs/cs/app/bootstrap.php.cache on line 1222
```

i thin the problem is in session, because if i comment the code for phpbb connect to function `createRequestFromFactory()` are passed 6 empty arrays, but when connect to phpbb to the samo function are passed phpbb objects.

Any idea how to do what i'm trying? Or another idea how to get data from phpbb user?

Comment: Do you want to use phpbb only for /forum/ part of your Symfony app?

Comment: forum is just a folder where is situated phpbb, i want to use phpbb user->data in symfony app not only in forum folder.